# ElectronNET generate 32 bit exe or other custom versions with dot net core project

Tags: electron.net

Electronize build a exe with target 32bit windows

When running the default code found on the official documentation `electronize build /target custom win7-x86;win32 /electron-arch ia32` simply fails to run, gives some console error.

Build Electron Application...
electronize.exe : Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Index was outside the bounds
of the array.)
At line:1 char:1

- electronize.exe build /target custom win-x86;win /dotnet-configuratio ...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine these methods to generate your target output type

Run this command `electronize build /custom...` [More info](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/152#issuecomment-557335542)
This give you details regarding the options available.

For 32bit windows

```
electronize.exe build /target custom "win-x86;win" /dotnet-configuration Debug /electron-arch ia32
```

The double quotes "win-x86;win" is the most important part, it is not there in the official documentation, so it will fail in package manager console